# Do the Maven property prefixes "user" and "maven" have special meaning?

Tags: java, maven

The [Maven POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) says that there are "five different styles" for maven properties:

```
 env.X: Prefixing a variable with "env." will return the shell's environment 
    variable. For example, ${env.PATH} contains the PATH environment variable.

 project.x: A dot (.) notated path in the POM will contain the corresponding 
    element's value. For example: <project><version>1.0</version></project> 
    is accessible via ${project.version}.

 settings.x: A dot (.) notated path in the settings.xml will contain the 
    corresponding element's value. For example: <settings>
    <offline>false</offline></settings> is accessible via 
    ${settings.offline}.

 Java System Properties: All properties accessible via 
    java.lang.System.getProperties() are available as POM properties, such 
    as ${java.home}.

 x: Set within a <properties /> element in the POM. The value of < 
    <properties><someVar>value</someVar></properties> may be used as 
    ${someVar}.
```

However, I've seen properties like `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` set on the command line and others like `user.home` used in various maven projects.  I think the former is set via maven plugins (not a part of the POM itself?), and have no idea about the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.home` is a Java System Properties, see `mvn help:system` for all available options.

`maven.test.skip` is a parameter defined by [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skip). The `maven.test`-part is a best practice to control which plugin must be skipped.
If a parameter of a maven-plugin can be set via commandline, you'll have to use the (User) property or expression as it was called in earlier docs. When there's no such key, you can't set if via commandline, but only inside the `pom.xml`